# Meaning of the '*' at the end of find tool

Tags: find

Recently I was asked to check why some `find` commands were skipping hidden folders and I figured out that issue was in having wildcard at the end of the path like here:

```bsh
find /path_to_folder/*
```

Output of the command above showed only regular files and folders skipping hidden folders

But if we'll do

```bsh
find /path_to_folder/
```

we can have all files and folders (including hidden).

Can somebody help me to understand this behaviour or point at where to look at to get more details? I tried to search in `find` manual but didn't get clear answer.

Comment: You would have found it on the manual of your shell. Google `shell expansion`.

Comment: Indeed, this related to `shell expansion` not `find` utility itself. Thanks @GeraldSchneider

Answer (score 0):

The `find` utility takes one or several search paths.  These are the first arguments to the utility before specifying further tests with predicates like `-name` and `-type`.

When you use `find /path_to_folder/*`, the shell would expand the globbing pattern `/path_to_folder/*` to the list of pathnames that matches it.  Each of these will be searched by `find`.  The `*` at the end of the pattern does not expand to hidden names by default.  The `find` utility will walk through each search path and find all names under them, including hidden names, but it will not search `/path_to_folder` itself because you didn't provide it with that pathname.

When you use `find /path_to_folder/`, you give `find` a single pathname as the search path.  The `find` utility will walk the `/path_to_folder` directory and its sub-directories, including hidden names.  In this case, it will find hidden names directly under `/path_to_folder` because you gave this pathname as the search path.

Summary:

- `/path_to_folder/*` is a globbing pattern that the shell will expand to a list of all matching non-hidden names under `/path_to_folder`.  These names under `/path_to_folder` will be used by `find` as search paths, but the list does not include `/path_to_folder` itself.
- Using `/path_to_folder/` as the single pathname, `find` will search that directory and find all things in or beneath it.